# What does xxxx_path mean in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to add new controller and model use name foo and foos_controller, hope foos_path can redirect. Doesn't work.

A origin code here (working):

```
href="<%= contacts_path %>"
```

After I add new controller and model follow name convention I try use the same (Not working):

```
href="<%= foos_path %>"
```

And this contacts_path is not defined anywhere else in rb project.
what does `xxxx_path` mean and how to use it?

Comment: It's defined by looking at the routes file.

Comment: @DaveNewton how to define in routes file? I cant find any define of contact_path in route file also.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @Noon It's defined by Rails *looking* at the routes file, finding the routes, and creating methods for each of them. All of this is covered in most Rails tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails follows convention to handle roots of application

when we execute this command

```
rails g scaffold foo
```

it generates routes along with your model, controller and views.

it generates a line in routes.rb as

```
 resources :foo
```

this line makes you access all the actions of your controller

for example:

```
foos_path: # redirects you to the  index page of your foos controller
new_foo_path: # redirects you to the create page of your foos controller etc.,
```

please go through this link for reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thank you it works!seems can't generate manually and separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your terminal and type `rake routes`, it will list your currently defined routes. On the left side you'll have their prefix. For example, `contacts` might route to the index action in `ContactsController`.

The `path` suffix is a way of referring to those routes inside your code.

If foos_path is giving you an error, that means you either have not yet defined that route for the resource, or you have but it is called something else (if you defined it manually with the `as:` option).

More info can be found in the [Rails Guide for Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best reading up on [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)

---

**Path Helpers**

Basically, the `path_helpers` of Rails are designed to help you define routes for your links etc in the most efficient way possible.

The bottom line is the path helper will take routes defined in your `config/routes.rb` and then allow you to call them dynamically - IE:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :photos #-> photos_path
```

The path `names` are typically from your `controllers`, allowing you to route to the various `actions` inside them. As Rails is built around being a `resourceful` structure, it will by default create routes for the "standard" controller actions:

[image]

---

**link_to**

In order to use the `path helpers` effectively, you'll be best using the [`rake routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes) command in cmd, or by simply typing an invalid url into your app's address bar

I notice you're using the standard HTML `<a href="">` tag in your question. You'll be much better suited to using the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper of Rails:

```
<%= link_to "text", your_path %>
```